# Reduce load time of a page that uses jQuery UI

Tags: php, performance, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

**Problem:** Some jQuery UI effects are quite slow to load, which is especially annoying when first loading a page.

For example, take the tabs widget. Sometimes I can see the underlying list during page load with jQuery tabs before the tabs widget has loaded (another slow mammoth is the accordion widget). I'd like to avoid this - i.e. speed it up somehow, or do it less "JavaScript heavy".

I have an idea for optimization of button widgets. In the markup itself, I could assign them all of the styles the `.button()` constructor would assign, and then I don't have to call `.button()` anymore. However, button is not the slowest, so this won't do much for my page load time.

**Similar Questions:**

- A response to [Jquery taking effect after the page is loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744476/jquery-taking-effect-after-the-page-is-loaded) suggests that I could call the tabs constructor in `$(document).ready()`, but I'm already doing that.
- The only trick I found in this area is to [Delay jQuery effects whilst page is loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874411/delay-jquery-effects-whilst-page-is-loading), which might be useful, but doesn't help much.

**Question 1:** Is there some easy way to prepare jQuery effects (like tabs) on the **PHP side**, and then do some lazy initialization of the jQuery UI widgets (to maintain the tabs' clickability)?

**Question 2:** Are there some good **guidelines** for what to avoid with jQuery UI to **not slow it down**, while maintaining a good user experience?

Comment: if clients netowrk is slow, the whole list will appear. accept it. one workaround is, put those blocks in `display:none` in css and then show when dom fully ready. will be very very ugly though.

Comment: I did a first step optimization for **tabs smoother loading** in answer to the question [Jquery taking effect after the page is loaded](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16843372/775066). I didn't post it as an answer here, coz I plan to do some further improvements to it (such as edit the jQuery tabs constructor).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**note:** This is just first step to answer. I intend to improve it, when I'll have time to play with disabling things in jQuery tabs constructor.

## Background:

There are a few little optimization you can do for **smoother loading of the `tabs`**. But it's basically trade-off to easy-to use. You add some css classes into your html already and don't wait till jQuery puts it for you. This avoids all the funny movements in the page when jQuery takes over, coz the elements will be already in place.

## Explained steps:

1) `div` containing all the tabs:

- You add class `ui-tabs` which in combination with step2 will suppress the original list and puts the navigation already in place.
- You add class `ui-widget` which fixes the font-size and the position of the first tab against navigation.

2) `ul` containing the nav items:

- You add class `ui-tabs-nav` which completes the list repositioning.

3) Each particular `div` containing tab panel, which is not active:

- You add `style="display:none;"`. This is what jQuery does anyway. So you don't have to remove style after the tabs are ready. jQuery does it for you. It also more fine-tuned than crudely hiding all content of tabs.

4) Is also good idea to put tabs constructor call in document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$( "#tabs" ).tabs();}
```

## Result:

So you change your html from [original](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>tabs-1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>tabs-2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>tabs-3 content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**to:**

```
<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs ui-widget">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>tabs-1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2" style="display:none;"><!-- display:none is later reverted by jQuery.tabs -->
        <p>tabs-2 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3" style="display:none;">
        <p>tabs-3 content</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Conclusion:

- You are just using jQuery styles.
- You tabs navigation and tab panels are already in place before jQuery starts rendering.
- No need any clean-up (E.g.: remove `display:none` from `ul`) after tabs are rendered.

Comment: Here is where to put ajax for loading tab content: [How to insert JavaScript upon showing a jQuery ui tab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1522017/775066)

Answer (score 0):

Question1: Is there some easy way how to prepare jQuery effect (tabs) at php side? And then do some effect lazy initialization (to maintain the tabs clickable)?

A: No. jQuery is manipulating the DOM and adding event handlers that php cant do anything about.

Question2: Also could be nice some guideline what to avoid with jQuery UI to not slow it down, while maintain user experience. Anyone knows about such guideline?

Reduce the amount of work that jQuery has to on ready/load. If you have a dozen tabs, only the  data in the initial one needs to be loaded by default, the rest can be lazy loaded. The same goes with your accordion, let ajax do the work when the user requests the content.

Don't show the content until it's ready. Set your elements hidden by default and show them after you initialize the tabs.I suggest using `visibility:hidden` if you decide to do this because it will reserve the space on the page for your element then just bring it into view when it's ready. `display:none` on the other hand would make other page elements be positioned as if that element didn't exist at all.